# RenderPositionedBox#63187 relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

**I constantly get this error:The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderPositionedBox#63187 relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE**

The relevant error-causing widget was:
ExpansionTile ExpansionTile:file:///D:/My%20Software/AMy%20projects/online%20shopping%20project/a_store_online_shop/lib/Widgets/category/main_category_widget.dart:23:18

I m getting above line error in below code:

```
main_category_widget.dart
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Expanded(
              child: FirestoreListView<MainCategory>(
                query: mainCategoryCollection(widget.selectedCat),
                itemBuilder: (context, snapshot) {
                  MainCategory mainCategory = snapshot.data();
                  return ExpansionTile(      //getting above error in this line  23:18
                    title: Text(mainCategory.mainCategory!),
                    children: [
                      SubCategoryWidget(
                        selectedSubCat: mainCategory.mainCategory,
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              ),
            );
          }
        }
```

**RenderObject: RenderPositionedBox#3e5ff relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
parentData:  (can use size)
constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=280.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
size: Size(280.0, 0.0)
alignment: Alignment.center
textDirection: ltr
widthFactor: expand
heightFactor: 1.0**

Getting above error after run GridView.builder,: Anyone Tell me how to solve this error
SubCategoryWidget.dart

```
class SubCategoryWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? selectedSubCat;
  const SubCategoryWidget({Key? key, this.selectedSubCat}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: FirestoreQueryBuilder<SubCategory>(
        query: subCategoryCollection(selectedSubCat: selectedSubCat),
        builder: (context, snapshot, _) {
          if (snapshot.isFetching) {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('error ${snapshot.error}');
          }

          return GridView.builder(    //after use get rendering error
            shrinkWrap: true,
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 3,
                childAspectRatio: snapshot.docs.length == 0 ? 1 / 1 : 1 / 1.1),
            itemCount: snapshot.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              SubCategory subCat = snapshot.docs[index].data();

              return InkWell(
                onTap: () {},
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 60,
                      width: 60,
                      child: FittedBox(
                        fit: BoxFit.contain,
                        child: Image.network(subCat.image!), //I cant get images from firestore
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      subCat.subCatName!,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```